# How to get the user id of a email from firebase email authentication

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I want to access the id (or uid ) of a email from firebase authentication . Its not the id of current users id, so i cant use firebase.auth().currentUser.uid. and i am also not in a position to store the uid in the database at the time of sign up and fetch it. is the anyway to fetch it directly from firebase authentication system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK supports looking up user information with an email:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

This method returns a UserRecord object for the user corresponding to the email provided.

If the provided email does not belong to an existing user or the user cannot be fetched for any other reason, the Admin SDK throws an error.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: When iam using this code i am getting an error  cant find variable admin

Comment: Do you use firebase-adnin?npm install firebase-admin --save
To use the module in your application, require it from any JavaScript file:

var admin = require('firebase-admin');
If you are using ES2015, you can import the module instead:

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

Comment: ohhh... i forgot to do that... and one more thing to ask, how to retrieve uid only from this json

Comment: `userRecord.uid` in the callback